# Is there a way to track edits to a question?

Tags: support, questions

One of my questions was just edited by someone else, but the editor did not really change anything. Is there a way to find out what changes he made to the question?

Comment: Hi! This does indeed look like a duplicate, so I'd recommend checking that one out. Even easier, as @Jeff Atwood pointed out in a comment, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) page in the Help Center clearly explains it. Hope that helps!